# How to use numba.SmartArrays for vector addition?

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, numba

I have written this code for vector addition using numba.SmartArrays. I am using this numba.SmartArrays for the first time. I am not sure how to use that.
        This code is not working and it is throwing errors.

```
    import numpy as np
    from numba import SmartArray,cuda, jit, uint32


    li1=np.uint32([1,2,3,4])
    li=np.uint32([1,2,3,4])
    b=SmartArray(li,where="host",copy=True)
    a=SmartArray(li1,where="host",copy=True)
    c=np.uint32([1,1,1,1])
    print type(li)
    print type(a)

    @cuda.jit('void(uint32[:],uint32[:],uint32[:])',type="gpu")
    def additionG(c,a,b):
        idx=cuda.threadIdx.x+cuda.blockDim.x*cuda.blockIdx.x

        if idx< len(a):
            a[idx]=c[idx]+b[idx]

    dA=cuda.to_device(a)
    dB=cuda.to_device(b)
    dC=cuda.to_device(c)
    additionG[1, 128](c,a,b)

    print a.__array__()
```

Errors:

```
    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
    <class 'numba.smartarray.SmartArray'>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\hp-pc\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\cuda\blowfishgpu_smart_arrays.py", line 20, in <module>
        dA=cuda.to_device(a)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 257, in _require_cuda_context
        return fn(*args, **kws)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\api.py", line 55, in to_device
        to, new = devicearray.auto_device(obj, stream=stream, copy=copy)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 403, in auto_device
        devobj.copy_to_device(obj, stream=stream)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 148, in copy_to_device
        sz = min(_driver.host_memory_size(ary), self.alloc_size)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 1348, in host_memory_size
        s, e = host_memory_extents(obj)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 1333, in host_memory_extents
        return mviewbuf.memoryview_get_extents(obj)
    TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

Comment: @Olivier De Meulder: Your edit *changed the code* in the question in a very signifcant way. Don't ever do that.

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while since I posted this question. Still posting the answer so that someone may find it helpful in future.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import SmartArray,cuda, jit, uint32,autojit

li1=np.uint32([6,7,8,9])
li=np.uint32([1,2,3,4])

a=SmartArray(li1,where='host',copy=True)
b=SmartArray(li,where="host",copy=True)

c=np.uint32([1,1,1,1])

def additionG(a,c):
    idx=cuda.threadIdx.x+cuda.blockDim.x*cuda.blockIdx.x

    if idx < len(c):
        a[idx]=a[idx]+c[idx]

    cuda.syncthreads()

bpg=1
tpb=128
dC=cuda.to_device(c)
cfunc = cuda.jit()(additionG)
cfunc[bpg, tpb](a,dC)

print a.__array__()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `cuda.to_device` doesn't handle smart arrays, which would sort of make sense, because smart arrays are supposed to do away with explicit copy management.

If my reading of the documentation is correct (I have never tried `SmartArray` before), you should just be able to change this

```
dA=cuda.to_device(a)
dB=cuda.to_device(b)
dC=cuda.to_device(c)
additionG[1, 128](c,a,b)
```

to just

```
dC=cuda.to_device(c)
additionG[1, 128](dC,a.gpu(),b.gpu())
```

The `.gpu()` method should return a GPU resident object that the kernel can understand and access.

Comment: Thanks @talonmies for your suggestion. I tried the same thing but still I am not able to resolve the errors. I am not sure about the signature decorator @jit that I am using.  `code`  @cuda.jit(uint32[:],uint32[:],uint32[:],type="gpu")
def additionG(c,a,b):

Comment: @SankalpVairat: the error you posted in your question is very clearly being produced by the line `dA=cuda.to_device(a)`- The JIT call should have nothing to do with the error